# using insert and update in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have this code in recording timein and timeout

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$query=mysql_query("Select * FROM tblattendance where IDNumber='" . $_POST['IDNumber'] . "' ");
list($exists) = mysql_fetch_row($query);

$idnumber=$row['IDNumber'];
$fname=$row['FirstName'];
$mname=$row['MiddleName'];
$lname=$row['LastName'];

if($exists){
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET TimeoutAM=CURTIME() WHERE IDNumber='" . $_POST['IDNumber'] . "' ORDER BY  Date DESC, TimeinAM DESC LIMIT 1"; 
}else{
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name SET Date=CURRENT_DATE(), TimeinAM=CURTIME(), IDNumber='$idnumber', FirstName='$fname', MiddleName='$mname', LastName='$lname' ";       
}
$result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

My problem is that if the IDNumber doesn't exist it will add a new record with timein and   then update the timeout. But when I tried to add again the same IDNumber it didn't add a   new record but instead it's just update the existing record the timeout columns. What shall  I do to add a record again?

Comment: It looks like you're using the "mysql" family of functions. Be aware that these functions are being *deprecated* and will eventually be *removed* from PHP. Please [switch to mysqli or PDO](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing) if at all possible.

Comment: Your code has [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Please consider switching to mysqli or PDO so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 0):

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). This will either insert or update.

Query:

```
 $idnumber = $_POST['IDNumber'];

INSERT INTO $tbl_name(IDNumber,Date,Timein,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) 
values( '$idnumber',CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), '$fname', =$mname', '$lname'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Timeout=CURRENT_DATE()
```

It is must that your first column be IDNumber as it follows the order of column to create filter and  update would interpret as follows:

```
UPDATE $tbl_name SET Timeout=NOW() WHERE IDNumber='" .   $_POST['IDNumber'] . "
```

code:

```
<?php
     $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(IDNumber,Date,Timein,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) 
    values( '$idnumber',CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), '$fname', =$mname', '$lname'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Timeout=CURRENT_DATE()";

    $result=mysql_query($sql); 
?>
```

Comment: i'm sorry but where should i put that code? in my php code or in my mysql? i'm using phpmyadmin. sorry i'm really new to this

Comment: sorry, i edited my codes above. please take a look at it again. although that code doesn't insert new record again.

Comment: you can do your insert and update using the my mentioned query at pne shot

Comment: what is pne shot? i tried your code it's keep on inserting but not updating

Comment: sry it to say one shot. spelling mistake!. Have you mentioned the first column as IDNumber as I have done => INSERT INTO $tbl_name(IDNumber,.... because it will use columns in that order to find does the record alreay exists

Comment: actually, my first column was already IDNumber. the code you gave me really add records but not updating. is it really ok if i use ON DUPLICATE KEY ON UPDATE to record same values in IDNumber column?